# NET8 Azure Function can't convert a json message from a service bus

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm creating a very simple `Azure Function` with `NET8`.

```
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("wordvoice", Connection = "SBConnectionString")] 
    string message)
{
    AudioServiceBusRequest request = 
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AudioServiceBusRequest>(message);

    await ProcessService.ProcessAudio(request, processName, _logger);
}
```

In the service bus, I add a simple `json` like that

```
{
    "wordId": 33,
    "language": 1,
    "word": "go"
}
```

[image]

I created a model to receive this json

```
public class AudioServiceBusRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("wordId")]
    public long? WordId { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("word")]
    public string Word { get; set; }
}
```

When the message is received by the Azure Function, I get at least 90 lines of errors starting with

> Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.language | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 17.)
>
> ---> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.language | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 17.
>
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string.

[image]

I'm using the same json in an Azure Function built with NET6 and it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining language and wordId as `string`...

```
[JsonPropertyName("language")]
public string Language { get; set; }
[JsonPropertyName("wordId")]
public string WordId { get; set; }
```

Change them to be `int` instead, to match your data.